# How to create a custom sprite [FiveM Lua]

Tags: image, lua, sprite, grand-theft-auto, fivem

I have been searching for a way to draw a custom image (.png) on screen.

When I started to look it up, I noticed everyone went for the UI way.

I've already asked how I could do this using one of FiveM's natives and I got the answer of `drawSprite()`

But now I have a new question; How can I create a custom sprite for the `drawSprite()` native to call upon?
And when I have this custom sprite, how do I use it in the `drawSprite()` native?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made your streamable .ytd resource?

Comment: No I don't; I'm entirely new to custom sprites et cetera. So I really don't have any clue as to what I have to do. Google isn't making me any wiser

Comment: On Stack, you need to be posting what you have been able to try, so we can assist you with the trouble you are having. How do I... posts are not allowed. But let me point you in the right direction. You will need knowledge of OpenIV, that is what you use to make and edit resources. Search for how to make resources, and then you will need to learn how to stream them. Once you have streaming resources down, the rest of sprite creating will likely make more sense. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, I'll try my best then, thanks for the heads up.
Didn't know these sort of posts aren't allowed, I guess I should read the TOS a bit better :P